# Return the part of a string before a character sequence in PHP

Tags: php, string, substring

I have a rawurlencoded string and want to get everything from the beginning of a string until a rawurlencoded newline (`%0A`) or carriage return (`%0D`) or the whole string if neither are in the string.

*Example*

From these strings:

```
First%20sentence.%0D%0ASecond%20Sentence.
Just%20one%20sentence.
```

I want to get these strings:

```
First%20sentence.
Just%20one%20sentence.
```

Basically I would like a function similar to `strtok($string, "\R")`, but that doesn't work because the string is rawurlencoded and the newline and carriage return characters have been turned into a sequence of three characters each.

Comment: why not `urldecode()` the string first?

Comment: @aynber You mean `rawurlencode(strtok(rawurldecode($string), "\R"))` ? The string is from a web from. Is there a security risk?

Comment: Not really, as long as you're not doing something that could possibly make it insecure, such as running it through `eval()`

Comment: Use `explode()` with `%0D` as the delimiter.

Comment: `strtok()` doesn't recognize regex, so `\R` will not equate to `\r\n`.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thank you! That one gave me a bit of a headache until I replaced it with `strtok($string, "\r\n")`. The [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) explains that the function uses *characters* as tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following to only remove the markers and any trailing characters *if* they exist in the string.

There is no reason to create an array then extract the first element from that temporary array; just remove the unwanted substring if it actually exists.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/IlsJf))

```
echo preg_replace('/(?:%0D|%0A).*/', '', $string);
```

More concisely: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Ss2AT))

```
echo preg_replace('/%0[AD].*/', '', $string);
```

---

If you are going to decode the string *anyhow*, then perform the truncation after that step. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/dhu4d))

```
echo strtok(rawurldecode($string), "\r\n");
```

The "character mask" contains the two entities `\r` and `\n` and the leading string will be returned before the first encountered character in that list.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice way to do it:

```
function getFirstLine ($query)
{
    $lines = preg_split('~%0A|%0D~', $query);

    return $lines[0];
}
```

This is probably the most readable solution... and it gives you the ability to access the remaining lines at any point.

This works in all cases:

```
$a = 'First%20sentence.';
echo getFirstLine($a), "\n"; // First%20sentence.

$b = 'First%20sentence.%0ASecond%20Sentence.';
echo getFirstLine($b), "\n"; // First%20sentence.

$c = 'First%20sentence.%0DSecond%20Sentence.';
echo getFirstLine($c), "\n"; // First%20sentence.

$d = 'First%20sentence.%0D%0ASecond%20Sentence.';
echo getFirstLine($d), "\n"; // First%20sentence.
```

Comment: Or just `preg_split('~%0A|%0D~', $string)[0]`, if I don't need a function.